# Could not install wireless display (additional feature) on windows 11

Tags: windows-11, screencasts

I want to cast my android phone's screen on to my laptop. So i need to install wireless display. However,  whenever i try to install it, it shows could  not install.

[image: IMAGE showing error]

Solutions that i tried:

1. Disabled metered network
2. Tried to install from cmd and powershell
3. Restarted laptop

Comment: Have you tried running the Windows update troubleshooter? Did you run Powershell as an administrator?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Your Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/your-phone/9nmpj99vjbwv#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) application (normally installed by default in Windows) along with the [Your Phone Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.appmanager&hl=en_GB&gl=US) on Android?

Comment: @Gantendo Yes i have

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for commenting. Yes i have used the app but there is no option for screencasting.